# Objective-C, best way to handle NSTask that isn't finished

Tags: objective-c, macos, dispatch, nstask

I have an asynchronous `dispatch queue` which reads data from large files in the background. During the course of that it does a few other things including some `NSTask` operations. The problem I'm facing is that I populate some variables with the result of those operations and the background queue has already moved on by the time those variables are ready (not NULL).

My code looks similar to the following:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    // reading large files
    ...
    NSTaskClass *operation = [[NSTaskClass alloc] init];
    NSString *result = [operation doTask:filePath];

    NSLog(@"result: %@" result); // returns NULL since task isn't done yet.
    ...
    // continue large file operations
});
```

Would would be the best way to handle this? I looked into creating a `callback` but I couldn't figure it out, and I'm not sure if that's even the right approach. Any advice on best practices is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's not background, it's another process. Do you really need read large file in another process? It's only make sense if you are running some server.

Answer (score 0):

**Just give you an idea, hope to solve your problem.**

- Use a `dispatch_sempahore` to handle the operations in your `NSTaskClass`
- Create a handler for `doTask` method, use `- (void)doTask:(NSString *)filePath handler:(void(^)(NSString *result))handler` instead of `- (NSString *)doTask:(NSString *)filePath`

Then, your code should look something like this:

```
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        // reading large files
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        ...
        NSTaskClass *operation = [[NSTaskClass alloc] init];
        [operation doTask:filePath handler:^(NSString * _Nonnull result) {
            // Get your result here
            result = [NSString stringWithString:result];

            ...

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);


        }];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        NSLog(@"result: %@" result); // Here should be fine (not NULL)
        ...
        // continue large file operations
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but it seems like once I call my `NSTaskClass` it never returns. I'm not exactly sure why. If you need any more information let me know, because I would like to get this working, thanks.

Comment: @JoeHabadas So, any background jobs in the object of `NSTaskClass`? If possible, could you please give me more detail about your code